# jQuery datepicker allow specific dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a basic problem and I think I almost found the solution but I can't tell what I did wrong.

I have a multiple jQuery datepicker and I don't want the user to be able to select non working days.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var sdate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if ($.inArray(sdate, enabledDates) !== -1) {
        return [true];
    }
    console.log(date);
    return [false];
}

$('#newOrderDates').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'yy-mm-dd',
    multidate: true,
    startDate : new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
});
```

So the datepicker will be able to select multiple dates and I don't want the user to be able to select past days and non working days.

The array enabledDates looks like this :

[image]

What I don't understant is the console displays the non working days, but for some reason, the user is still able to select them with the datepicker ! I guess the error is coming from the return[true] and return [false] but I didn't find any relevant documentation to fix this so far.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Louis

Comment: please refer to my earlier post, I have added snippet with sample example in which I disabled the desired dates, you can do the same. in case of required any help let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example of **bootstrap datepicker**, you can restrict or enabled/disabled dates based on the requirement.

```js
var enabledDates = new Array('2020-01-12', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-18', '2020-01-30', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-10');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#newOrderDates").datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    multidate: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var sdate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      if ($.inArray(sdate, enabledDates) !== -1) {
        return {
          enabled: true
        }
      } else {
        return {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

.ui-datepicker {
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="newOrderDates">
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply !

I think you misunderstood my post though. In the array enabledDates, I only want the dates that are enabled (you disabled the dates in your array). 

This still doesn't work for me.. This is bootstrap datepicker by the way, my mistake

Comment: @LouisCharles okay no worries, let me update the post as per your requirement.

Comment: @LouisCharles I have made the changes, updated code using bootstrap datepicker as well as enabled only those dates which are specified other dates are disabled. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example of **jquery datepicker**, you can restrict or enabled/disabled dates based on requirement.

```js
var enabledDates = new Array('2020-01-12', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-18', '2020-01-30', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-10');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#newOrderDates").datepicker({
      todayHighlight: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      multidate: true,
      startDate: new Date(),
      beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
    });
  });

  function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var sdate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if ($.inArray(sdate, enabledDates) !== -1) {
      return [true];
    }

    return [false];
  }
})
```

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

.ui-datepicker {
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="newOrderDates">
```

Comment: @LouisCharles  i have added an example using jquery datepicker as well.

Comment: Thanks again, this is still not working though.. The console displays the correct date but the input is still possible

Comment: @LouisCharles i don't get your point related to input can you explain again.

Comment: I've updated the original post.. do you have an idea why I don't get it right ?